# Swift - Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range error question

Tags: swift

```
var imageFileName = ["Ahri.jpg", "Bard.jpg", "batman.jpg", "Janna.jpg", "spiderman.jpg", "Twisted Fate.jpg"]

@IBOutlet var pickerImage: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet var lblImageFileName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for i in 0 ..< MAX_ARRAY_NUM {
        let image = UIImage(named: imageFileName[i])
        imageArray.append(image)
    }
```

this is my Swift code and it keeps "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" error is coming "let image = UIImage(named: imageFileName[i])" this point so how can I fix this one

Comment: What's `MAX_ARRAY_NUM`? Where is it declared and set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
for imageName in imageFileName {
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    imageArray.append(image)
}
```

It will avoid crashes and it will loop all your elements

Answer (score 2):

First of all the name `imageFileName` for an array (singular) is misleading. An array should be named in plural form: `imageFileNames`

---

Basically don't use hard-coded constants for the number of items in a collection type. This is the reason for the crash.
And don't use pure index based `for` loops to enumerate arrays in Swift.

In most cases – most likely also in this one – you need only the element but not the index

```
for imageName in imageFileNames { ...
```

In the rare cases you really need the index use Fast Enumeration

```
for (index, imageName) in imageFileNames.enumerated() { ...
```

or

```
for (index, _) in imageFileNames.enumerated() { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your crash depends on `MAX_ARRAY_NUM` value. I can guess it's more than 6. Then when you try to access `imageFileName[7]` it crashes as there is no element at this position.

The best solution would be to loop over your items, unrelating of any index.

DionizB's solution works. But I would like to post mine :

`imageArray = imageFileName.map { return UIImage(named: $0) }`